# SimGrid-3.13 Can't load classes

Tags: java, simgrid

There are steps for building .jar file of SimGrid.

I downloaded archive from [here](https://ci.inria.fr/simgrid/job/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode=Debug,node=simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/). 
Then I made following

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/Documents/simgrid -Denable_maintainer_mode=off -Denable_compile_optimizations=off -Denable_java=on -Denable_model-checking=off
make
make check
```

`100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 586`

```
ctest
```

`100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 586`

```
make install
```

There is `simgrid.jar` in SimGrid-3.13 folder.
But when I write code I can't load classes from this .jar file. 
How can I fix it?

**UPDATED** 
If I download ready `simgrid.jar` from [thence](https://ci.inria.fr/simgrid/job/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode=Debug,node=simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/), error occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/simgrid-java2166199247712718748/libsimgrid.so: libcgraph.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where I have to add `libsimgrid-java.so`, `libsimgrid.so`?

**UPDATED2**
After installing `graphviz  graphviz-dev`. New error occurs

```
Invalid XML (XML input line 2, state 2): Bad declaration <!DOCTYPE platform SYSTEM "http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/simgrid.dtd">.
If your are using a XML v3 file (check the version attribute in <platform>), please update it with tools/simgrid_update_xml.pl
[0.000000] /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/surf/xml/surfxml_sax_cb.cpp:55: [surf_parse/ERROR] Parse error at (null):2: Parse error in /home/ken/IdeaProjects/Sim2Sim/src/main/java/LHCb/platform.xml
[0.000000] /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/surf/xml/surfxml_sax_cb.cpp:57: [xbt/CRITICAL] Exiting now
```

Comment: Is it present in your classpath? if you are using eclipse, you can add external jars to the project

Comment: I am using Intellij Idea. I add this .jar in File/Project Structure/Dependecy/Add jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the second update, you should read the error message that you copy-pasted:

`If your are using a XML v3 file (check the version attribute in <platform>), please update it with tools/simgrid_update_xml.pl`

Can you confirm that:

- (1) the `version` attribute in the `<platform>` is `3`
- (2) running the [tools/simgrid_update_xml.pl script](https://github.com/mquinson/simgrid/blob/master/tools/simgrid_update_xml.pl) on the platform fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes, version is 3.

Comment: The script is here: https://github.com/mquinson/simgrid/blob/master/tools/simgrid_update_xml.pl

Answer (score 2):

I just checked the [Debian package search page](http://packages.debian.org), in the second search box. I looked for `/usr/lib/libcgraph.so.6` and it says that this library is in the package `libcgraph6`. So you have to `apt-get install libcgraph6` to get it.